# MySQL - delete rows from multiple tables in large tables

Tags: mysql

I have three tables and I am trying to delete rows from all table in one query. These are large tables

```
CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
  `aid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`aid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `cid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `aid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cid`),
  KEY (`aid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `pid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `ts` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pid`),
  KEY (`cid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

If I use following query, it only deletes if matching rows are present in every table. Say, products does not have any matching rows, the rows from categories are also not deleted

```
delete c, p from accounts a inner join categories c on a.aid=c.aid inner join products p on p.cid=c.cid and a.aid < 123 and a.aid > 63;
```

if I use following query, MySQL seems to be creating a huge joined table before deleting, and hence the query is extremely slow

```
delete c, p from accounts a left join categories c on a.aid=c.aid left join products p on p.cid=c.cid and a.aid < 123 and a.aid > 63;
```

Any better way of achieving the same?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using cascading deletion:

```sql
CREATE TABLE accounts (
    aid int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (aid)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE categories (
    cid int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    aid int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (cid),
    FOREIGN KEY (aid) REFERENCES accounts (aid) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE products (
    pid int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    cid int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    ts int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (pid),
    FOREIGN KEY (cid) REFERENCES categories (cid) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

With the cascading deletion approach, when deleting an account, MySQL will automatically cascade the deletion to include the child category and product records associated with that account.

If you wanted to stick with your current approach, you might look into indexing the join conditions.  But cascading deletion is likely to be the most performant and also easiest to use approach.

Here are some index suggestions.  For starters you may index the foreign keys in the `categories` and `products` tables:

```sql
CREATE INDEX c_idx ON categories (aid);
CREATE INDEX p_idx ON products (cid);
```

MySQL might be able to use these indices to speed up the join crtieria.